# Yii2: model not loading array

Tags: php, yii2

I am using the following (simple) code for a model to be used with a form in yii2:

```
class ChooseAgeCategoriesForm extends Model
{

    public $ageCategories;

    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['ageCategories', 'safe'],
            [['ageCategories'], 'each', 'rule' => ['integer']],
        ];
    }
}
```

However, then trying to load the model like this:

```
$model = new ChooseAgeCategoriesForm();

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $acIDs = $model->ageCategories;
}
```

The code is never executed. In fact, `$model->load` returns `Bool(false)` but `$model->errors` is empty. Dumping the content of `post` yields this result:

```
array(2) { ["_csrf"]=> string(56) "SzhjdWIuc0oIQSA0BEs4BDp8KzYEXwM5CG80RhNBRDkPUzIXO1gBew==" ["ageCategories"]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" [3]=> string(1) "4" [4]=> string(1) "5" [5]=> string(1) "6" [6]=> string(1) "7" [7]=> string(1) "9" [8]=> string(2) "10" } }
```

So yes, the field is actually sent and filled with an array of numbers. What don't I see here, what is the problem? Thanks in advance. I also tried to add `['ageCategories', 'exist', 'allowArray' => true],` as another rule, but this does not work either. Any ideas?

**Form code**

As requested, the code of the form itself:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => Url::to(['/result/team-result']),
    'method' => 'post',
    'options' => ['id' => 'chooseAgeCategory', 'style' => "margin-bottom: 15px;"]
]); ?>

<?= Select2::widget([
    'name' => 'ageCategories',
    'id' => 'ac-id',
    'value' => $acIDs,
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(AgeCategory::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
    'options' => ['multiple' => true, 'placeholder' => Yii::t('view', 'Select Age Category')],
    'pluginEvents' => [
        "change" => "function() { this.form.submit(); }",
    ]
]) ?>

<?php $form->end(); ?>
```

Comment: Show your form's code

Comment: Added the form's code to the question.

Comment: What is variable `$model`'s class?

Comment: `$model` is initialized as `$model = new ChooseAgeCategoriesForm();`, hence `ChooseAgeCategoriesForm` which is derived from `yii\base\Model`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your select2 widget code like below. Yii2 wrapping model name with field name like

> ChooseAgeCategoriesForm[ageCategories]

If you inspect your form you will come to know. SO you have to give model value in the select2 widget.

```
<?= Select2::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'ageCategories',
    'id' => 'ac-id',
    'value' => $acIDs,
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(AgeCategory::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
    'options' => ['multiple' => true, 'placeholder' => Yii::t('view', 'Select Age Category')],
    'pluginEvents' => [
        "change" => "function() { this.form.submit(); }",
    ]
]) ?>
```

Ref: http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the `Select2` using the `model` attribute, so that would be automatically linked to the field easing the loading process and also using your model's validation functions:

```
<?= Select2::widget([
    'name' => 'ageCategories',
    'id' => 'ac-id',
    'value' => $acIDs,
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(AgeCategory::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
    'options' => ['multiple' => true, 'placeholder' => Yii::t('view', 'Select Age Category')],
    'pluginEvents' => [
        "change" => "function() { this.form.submit(); }",
    ]
]) ?>
```